# How to Stop Azure IIS Appending Error Status Code Query String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, http-error

I have the following setup in my web.config file to handle errors:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/internalservererror/" />
</httpErrors>
```

When I throw an exception in my app it works fine locally but it redirects to the following URL in error-page in azure (note that the page I threw the exception from is at the end of the URL:

> https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/error/internalservererror/?500;https://example.com/about/

How do I stop IIS from exibiting this behaviour in Azure?

Comment: Just tried your configuration but cannot reproduce this behavior, both work fine when running locally and published to azure. I am wondering whether you have other redirection rules on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a question mark at the end of your path parameter, using your code you would have something like this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/internalservererror/?" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: I'm unable to resolve the issue with this answer? I'm using Rehan's MVC 5 Boilerplate template.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the logic behind of this? btw it is not worked.